# Getting tag and text from multiple nested children in Python - calling same function in itself

Tags: python-3.x, xml

I have an xml block and would like to retrieve all nested children. I have the following:

```
    import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
    

class MyParser:
    def __init__(self, xml_block):
        self.xml_block = xml_block

def main(self):
        tree = ET.ElementTree(ET.fromstring(self.xml_block))
        root = tree.getroot()
        self.get_tag_and_text(root)


def get_tag_and_text(self, root):
    keys_and_values = {}
    for child in root:
        if child.text is not None:
            keys_and_values[child.tag] = child.text
        self.get_tag_and_text(child)
```

As you can see, the function get_tag_and_text calls itself, refreshing the root with child.
However the keys_and_values variable doesn't get returned with all the contents, it only returns when the for loop is finished. At which point, the keys_and_values dict only contains the last valid entry. How can I loop this correctly, so that all keys/values are collected and then returned?

**Example xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<abc:random xmlns:abc="http://www.mywebsite.com" schemaVersion="1.2">
<abc:header>
<abc:number>8</abc:number>
<abc:type>text/xml</abc:type>
</abc:header>
<abc:body>
<abc:d>
<abc:purpose>start</abc:purpose>
</abc:d>
</abc:body>
</abc:random>
```

Comment: The code in the question is incomplete. We cannot run it. A proper [mcve] (including an XML sample) would make it easier to help.

Comment: @mzjn I added example xml.

Comment: Python code is still incomplete. No `import` statements, no `class` definition, bad indentation...

Comment: @mzjn: I just changed the code again

Comment: The code is clearly part of a class. The `class` definition is still missing.

Comment: @mzjn: I'm not sure why the class is so important here, in any case I just edited it.

Comment: I have asked you to provide code that we can actually run. Do you really find that strange? Now you have introduced even more bad indentation.

Comment: @mzjn: I give up. Not sure what exactly you can't run here, the xml is there, the function is there.

Comment: You need to understand the concept of a [mcve]. We should be able to copy, paste and run the code in the question. We should not have to point out obvious errors or omissions. Before you post any code, you should test it yourself and make sure that it actually reproduces the problem.